# python textbox highlight with selectable menu items

Tags: python, menu, textbox, highlight

I am using Python 2.7.13 and I am trying to build a GUI that uses textbox and I need to put a menu inside the textbox that I can select different items of that menu with a highlighted cursor.I want to be able to select these items by having up and down arrow buttons and a enter button.I have searched and searched and found nothing that could help me with this problem.

Comment: This is not a question. Come back when you have code and some specific question. In the mean while google a `tkinter` tutorial.

Comment: What widget framework are you using?

Comment: I am familiar with Tkinter and use it for my GUI now and can not find anything on what I am trying to do If I did I honestly would not be trying to waste your time.I have searched and searched without nothing

Comment: I am using Tkinter

Comment: I am not asking for someone to do my work for me I wont learn that way I just need pointed in the right direction on what to use to build it.